# tableView in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, audio-player

I need some help with the code below.  For some reason the song list is not getting displayed in the table.  Everything looks good from my end.  If anyone can see something obvious please point it out. Here is my swift code:

```
    func getMusicFilesInDirectory() -> [String] {

    // get the documents folder url
    let documentsUrl =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!

    // get the directory contents (including folders)
    do {
        let directoryContents = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions())
        print(directoryContents)

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    // filter the directory to extract only Wav Files

    do {
        let directoryUrls = try  NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions())
        print(directoryUrls)
        let wavFilesDir = directoryUrls.filter(){ $0.pathExtension! == "wav" }.map{ $0.lastPathComponent! }
        wavFiles = ["Music Files:\n" + wavFilesDir.description]
       } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
     return wavFiles
                                       }
// table view
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //return wavFiles.count;
    return getMusicFilesInDirectory().count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = getMusicFilesInDirectory()[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = wavFiles[indexPath.row]
   return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("You selected cell#\(indexPath.row)")}
```

After following some of the leads from the guys below I modified the code and added the following methods.  Currently I am still not getting the list to display in my table and the reason is because the music files are not accessible in the directory stored.  Once they get moved to the document directory everything should be resolved.    I will post another updated when this is done.

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath   indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    getFileCount({(success: Bool, error: String)-> Void in
        if success{
            tableView.reloadData();
        } else {
            print("No wave files Found");
        }
        })
    //print("You selected cell#\(indexPath.row)")
       }

func getFileCount (completionHandler : (success: Bool, error: String) -> Void) -> [String] {
    if wavFiles.count > 0 {
        completionHandler(success: true, error: "none");
    }else {
        completionHandler(success: false, error: "No files found");
    }
    return wavFiles
    }
```

Comment: Where do you `reloadData` the tableview? Maybe you forgot?

Comment: I think having a completion handler would be a useful way since you're not reloading the data after it is loaded. 
Just a suggestion : It would be better if you store the result of your getMusicFilesInDirectory that calling the function everytime a cell is populated.

Comment: @Eric D, @ kaizoku,  excellent suggestions guys.  Trying to figure out where to reload the data.

Comment: Ok so what you can do is make a completionHandler in the function definition. When calling this function on a variable, define the body of the completion handler and there you can write reloadData. So as soon as the whole data set is loaded, your tableView.reloadData will be called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func sampleFunction (completionHandler : (success : Bool, error : String) -> Void) -> [String] {
    var someVariable = ["value1","value2","value2"];
    if someVariable.count > 0 {
        completionHandler(success: true, error: "");
    } else {
        completionHandler(success: false, error: "Some Problem");
    }
    return someVariable;
}

var dataHolder = sampleFunction({(success: Bool, error : String)-> Void in
    if success{
        tableView.reloadData();
    } else {
        print("Some Error");
    }
})
```

This is a sample code that you can try to implement. 
I suggested completion handler because you are getting all your values from some external source or similar, hence the executing procedures will be completed while the retrieving part works in background. 
So using these handlers everytime is not necessary.

Comment: followed your suggestion but I am not getting any data.  My  "return wavFiles" method above returns an empty array.  Working on that issue right now.

Comment: Oh, then there has to be some error in the retrieve data method. Try adding breakpoints and finding the mistake

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  I think I am inside the wrong directory.  Trying to figure out how to retrieve the contents of my app directory or the iTunes library.  Any hints would be appreciated

Comment: I am now able to get the code above to work thanks to your hints.  What I am missing is the ability to access the .wav files.  The directory "documents" see code below  does not have any files in it:                                                            let directoryUrls = try  NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions())
        print(directoryUrls)

Comment: Oh thats great! If you feel ive helped then please accept the answer :)
Good Luck :)